# if isEmpty issue

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have issue about code decor.

for example i should handle objects from DAO

```
val user1 = DAO.get(token)
val user2 = DAO.get(token)
val user3 = DAO.get(token)
```

Next I should check user.isDefined

```
if (user1.isEmpty || user2.isEmpty || user3.isEmpty ) {
return "error..."
}
else {
 ... 
}
```

Mentioned code looks like imperative style, can it be more functional? How can I change if to the more functional way ?

BR!

Comment: what is the return type of DAO.get()?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `DAO.get` returns an `Option[User]`, you can use a for comprehension to specify what should happen if all 3 options are a `Some`. Then, use `getOrElse` to specify what should happen otherwise.

```
val success: Option[String] = for {
    x <- DAO.get(token)
    y <- DAO.get(token)
    z <- DAO.get(token)
} yield "retrieved 3 users"

success getOrElse "error"
```

Answer (score 1):

`exists` should help you:

```
if (List(user1, user2, user3).exists(_.isEmpty))
    // error
    ...
else // ok
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List(user1,user2,user3).find(_.isEmpty) match {
    case Some(x) => "error"
    case None => ...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say `find` is the function of choice here, because it will return the **first** nonempty user, while OP probably wants to do logic with all the `user`s, and definitely wants to make sure **none** of the `user`s are empty.

Comment: You're still using `find`, which will only return the **first** empty user.

Comment: if it doesn't find empty user then None case is executed. If any of users is empty then Some case is - exactly the same logic as with OP if-else.

Comment: You're right, I had misunderstood the solution. Still, I don't find this solution very readable because, if I understood it correctly this time, the error case returns a `Some(None)`, and the success case returns a `None`.

Comment: error case will return Some(user) whre user.isEmpty==true. And None will indicate that all users are not empty - it does not have to return somethin more.

Comment: i thought the `_.isEmpty` indicated that `user` 1 to 3 are `Option[User]`. This is why I believe it will return `Some[None]`.

Answer (score 0):

@ka4eli's solution is OK, but I think it's a bit convoluted, because if an empty `user` exists, the result will be a `Some(None)`, which I find confusing.

If I may suggest a cleaner solution, admittedly inspired by @ka4eli's answer:

```
val userOpts = (1 to 3).map(_ => DAO.get(token))

if (userOpts.forall(_.nonEmpty)) {
  // everything OK
  val users = userOpts.map(_.get)
  // do your thing with users
} else {
  // error
}
```

The `forall` function tests a predicate on all the elements of a collection - in this case that the element is not empty.

If you want to know *which* of the `user`s is empty, you will need to employ more complex logic.

Comment: see my comments, the result won't be Some(None)

Comment: won't work. As it will fail even if the first user is defined and the others aren't. The described code in the code would short-circuit.

Comment: @AndreasNeumann yes, the intention was to fail as long as at least one of the `user`s is empty, just like in OP's question: `if (user1.isEmpty || user2.isEmpty || user3.isEmpty ) {
return "error..."
}`